# How can I select a sequence of objects by moving mouse in Unity?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I have a board of tiles in my game in **Unity** and I have to select a sequence of tiles by moving the pressed mouse over the tiles like if I would select letters in a such game like on the screenshot. Please, hint me, how can I implement this functionality. I'm just a newby in Unity.

[image]

Comment: What is your build target? Mobile, like in the screenshot, or PC/Linux/Mac?

Comment: Mobile, for Android and iOS.

Comment: I think using the mouse-enter triggers to queue the object id into an array so you have the order is probably the route you'd want to look into. Do a search for mouse-over events. You should get some good examples. I know for a fact there are several youtube videos about object selection.

Comment: if you know how to find those videos, please share them with me

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHeem-mywDk should get you started. Couple with that the check for mouse down and you know the difference between the mouse just passing over, and a selection attempt.

Comment: When you get a working solution, be sure to post an answer to your question to help out others who may have the same question. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

A solution for my problem is using this two methods `OnMouseEnter()` and `OnMouseExit`.